# Passing a Parameter in the subject line of php email

Tags: php, email, html-email

I am trying to pass as the subject line an input parameter that a user has entered.  When I try this:

```
$mail->Subject ='.$vehicle_type';
```

It prints out `.$vehicle_type` as the subject of the email rather than the parameter it holds.

I'm a newbie here.  Tried searching this but it seems that all examples just pass a text string rather than passing the input parameter.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to read the PHP manual and learn how single quotes and double quotes operate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you pass a String towards the variable.

```
$item->something = '$var';
```

will pass the string "$var".

The reason double quotes (might) work is because the PHP interpeter will try to parse variables it finds in the string.

If you don't want to add anything else

```
$mail->Subject = $vehicle_type;
```

will work.

If you want to add extra string parts to the variable you can use

```
$mail->Subject = "Vehicle type: " . $vehicle_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
$mail->Subject = $vehicle_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with this :

```
 $mail->Subject =$vehicle_type; or $mail->Subject ="'".$vehicle_type."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$mail->Subject = $vehicle_type;`